# Laravel 9 validation.unique error text is not shown

Tags: laravel-9

WHen a user tries to register and a user with the same name already exists, there is "validation.unique" shown.
This error says nothing for users and they don't understand why register is not possible.
Could you guys help me to make an error message visible?
Under lang-> en/de ->validation.php there is a list of messages (?) But they are not displayed.
TThank you !

I tried to add a custom message in validation.php like this:

```
'custom' => [
   'attribute-name' => [
        'rule-name' => 'custume-message',
],
   'name' => [
      'unique' => 'Ein Benutzer mit diesem Namen ist bereits registriert',
]
],
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved that:
it was easy because I didn't have a file named validation.php under resources/lang, I only needed to add it.